# error after bulkcopy

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I keep getting this error

System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at Default2.atasks_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

```
Using bcp As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(conn)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 7)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 5)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 10)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(7, 13)
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(8, 6)
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.stagingtasks"
    bcp.WriteToServer(table)
End Using

conn.Open()

cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.taskadding"
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd1.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

i get the same error doing it this way too

```
 conn.Open()
        Using bcp As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(conn)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 7)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 5)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 10)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(7, 13)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(8, 6)
        bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.stagingtasks"
        bcp.WriteToServer(table)
        bcp.Close()

    End Using

    conn.Close()


    atasks.Visible = False
    UpdatePanel2.Update()
    Label2.Visible = False


    conn.Open()
    cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.taskadding"
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd1.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

however, the bulk copy works, the other part doesnt

Comment: Same error? ok, why not just remove the first conn.Close and the second conn.Open and see if that works. If that does not work, create a new connection conn_new and see if the second part works fine (just to make sure it is working)

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy is opening the connection, after the End Using you try to open it again.

Either close the connection after the bulk copy, or don't attempt to open it again before the sproc execution.

Comment: I agree, was writing in parrallel

Comment: just before the conn.Open() call that is failing do if(!conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open){ conn.Open(); }

Comment: that didnt work either i dont know lett me see what error i get now

Answer (score 0):

You do a conn.Open just before your "dbo.taskadding" but that is already opened by SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd1.Connection = conn
```

wow how did i miss that

Comment: That would have a different error message not the same one :P

Comment: well haha i guess a mix of what i changed and this helped